# Compare two XML files or two DataSets and get differences

Tags: xml, datatable

**Problem :**

I have two XML files, one with expected results and one with detected results.
The structure is exactly the same, only the values change. I want to compare and get the difference between both.

I have felt upon the Microsoft XMLDiffPatch tool but I cannot retrieve the different values directly.

**Example :**

File 1

```
<NameValue>
  <Name>PARAM_Currency</Name>
  <Value>USD</Value>
  <Type>VARCHAR</Type>
</NameValue>
```

File 2

```
<NameValue>
  <Name>PARAM_Currency</Name>
  <Value>CAD</Value>
  <Type>VARCHAR</Type>
</NameValue>
```

I want three values to be returned, the Name, expected and detected value.

PARAM_Currency, USD, CAD

I though of comparing two DataSets or DataTable, I am not sure this si the good way to do.